How to update list from apt list --upgradeable
Listed Packages for upgrading
I can't seem to make any command work for lists; Sometimes the terminal will instruct me on what to do and it's generally easy to find tips on Google. I've tried sudo apt update and sudo apt upgrade along with sudo apt full-upgrade and it constantly says 0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 4 not upgraded.
I can't seem to target those packages with any command. Any ideas?

sudo apt upgrade

That yields: The following packages have been kept back:
ckb-next python3-update-manager update-manager update-manager-core
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 4 not upgraded.
I'd stated that I wanted to reach those packages and update them... Apparently my post is -1 now... What did I do wrong?

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Does this answer your question? What are phased updates, and why does Ubuntu use them?

You have mixed software sources from Ubuntu 22.04 (jammy) and Ubuntu 24.04 (noble) in your /etc/apt/sources.list file. Mixing software sources from different releases can cause package management problems. Please edit your /etc/apt/sources.list file to be fully compatible with Ubuntu 24.04 by following the instructions in What is the correct output of cat /etc/apt/sources.list?.
It is not recommended to upgrade packages held back by phased updates!!! Phased updates are designed to protect users from potential issues by ensuring a controlled and tested rollout process. Manually upgrading packages held back by phased updates bypasses these safeguards and can expose your system to risks that phased updates are meant to mitigate. In addition prematurely upgrading packages held back by phased updates can break your package management so badly that there is no alternative to completely reinstalling Ubuntu!

To upgrade the packages listed in the results of apt list --upgradable run the following commands.
for pkg in $(apt list --upgradable 2>/dev/null | awk -F/ 'NR>1 {print $1}'); do
  sudo apt upgrade "$pkg"
done


apt list --upgradable 2>/dev/null: Lists the upgradable packages, suppressing error messages.
awk -F/ 'NR>1 {print $1}': Uses awk to split each line by the / character and print the package name ($1). The NR>1 condition ensures that the header line is skipped.
sudo apt upgrade "$pkg": Upgrade each package found by the for pkg in $(apt list --upgradable 2>/dev/null | awk -F/ 'NR>1 {print $1}'); command. The do .... done loop ensures that each package is upgraded.


If you don't want to risk breaking your system by running the above commands try these ones instead.
for pkg in $(apt list --upgradable 2>/dev/null | awk -F/ 'NR>1 {print $1}'); do
  apt --simulate upgrade "$pkg"
done


"In addition upgrading packages held back by phased updates can break your package management so badly that there is no alternative to completely reinstalling Ubuntu!" That's surprising considering that for many years there were no phased upgrades.

@OrganicMarble Thanks for commenting. In order to make this point more clear I edited this sentence to "In addition prematurely upgrading packages held back by phased updates can break your package management so badly that there is no alternative to completely reinstalling Ubuntu!"
